# Font awesome icon is not getting displayed in angular web app

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I have the following in my package.json

```
  "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.29",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.1",
```

I am trying to use a font awesome icon in my html page as follows:

```
       <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
```

However, this icon fa-clock-o is not getting displayed. If I change the icon to something else like fa-map-marker, then that gets displayed without any issues. What am I missing here?

Also, I notice that even though fa-map-marker looks like a pin in the documentation, it is getting displayed a solid icon with fully filled body. Not sure why the icon does not match the documentation. Is there a way to turn off the solid look of the icon?
By solid I mean the following:
[image]

I want it to be like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to use "fas" instead of "fa" class. This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

clock-o is fontawesome v4.
[link of clock-o](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/clock-o)

if you want to use clock-o, you need to version down.

fontawesome v5 can search this site.
[fontawesome version 5](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)